# Laravel using of resource

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm new to Laravel and I'm working around with it.

I have a folder in views called 'cp'. in cp folder I can add/remove new slider through index.blade.php and also add new products through product.blade.php. I want to update my products too but when I submit the form It goes to the wrong route ( blog.dev/product/6 ).

I also attached 4 screenshots that shows the pages.

Could you please help me with that.

This is web.php:

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@index');
Route::get('درباره-ما', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('تماس-با-ما', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('غذای-سگ', 'PagesController@dogs');
Route::get('/cp/product', 'ProductController@product');
Route::get('/cp/product/{id}/edit/', 'ProductController@edit');
Route::resource('product','ProductController');
Route::resource('cp', 'PostsController');
Auth::routes();
```

screenshot1: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GSFDbPj.jpg

screenshot2: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GSFDNRq.jpg

screenshot3: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GSFEi1a.jpg

screenshot4: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GSFCI6F.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Laravel read the route from the top and stop at the first match, so put the more restrictive route at the top

Try something like this : (unfortunately I can't check the non-latin alaphabet, maybe you can also comment them if you still have issue - just to be sure it's not a cause too)

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@index');
Route::get('درباره-ما', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('تماس-با-ما', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('غذای-سگ', 'PagesController@dogs');
Route::get('/cp/product/{id}/edit/', 'ProductController@edit');
Route::get('/cp/product', 'ProductController@product');
Route::resource('product','ProductController');
Route::resource('cp', 'PostsController');
Auth::routes();
```

Can you tell me if it's working ?

Comment: there is no issue with the non-latin part, I tried the change you mentioned but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

update method available only PUT|PATCH method

change your request url

/product/6?_method=PUT 
now you can use POST method for update